# Swift Equivalent to Java Reflection Types

Tags: swift

Is there an equivalent in Swift to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType and java.lang.reflect.Type? I am converting some Java code and am wondering how you would go about referencing and working with Types of objects in Swift.

Comment: [Mirror?](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html)  Or use `Any` or `AnyObject`.

Comment: It looks like I can store types as Any.Type and get that type using .self or .dynamicType. This works well for Type. I am having trouble with ParameterizedType as it seems the only option I have found so far is [String].dynamicType.Element().dynamicType. It works even if the list is empty.